# Changing a numeric month to a name month in pandas or SQL

Tags: sql, pandas

I have a column 'date' that reads as 2018-01-02 02:06:21 and I want to convert to read as 
2018-January-01-02 02:06:21 - Essentially making numeric date to read month name, I have been struggling.  The code I am using:

This is using pandas but can also try and convert into SQL and then bring it over.

df['date'] = df['date'].strftime('%Y-%m') and the error I get when doing this

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try using `%MMMM`

Comment: Which database are you using? Date functions widely vary across databases.

Comment: I am using padas currently but brought that in from SQL

Comment: SQL is a language (not short for any DBMS). Please tag the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

1) The best you can get with the minimal effort `pandas` is:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = ['2018-01-02 02:06:21']

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date'] = pd.Series(dates)

df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%Y-%b-%m-%H:%M:%S'))

print(df)
```

Output: `2018-Jan-01-02:06:21`

2) As for `SQL`. Different `SQL` products have different means for date formatting. You need to proper tag your question first.

***I see that you ask a series of questions about how to accomplish one task. Reading though those questions I get a feeling that you wish to make a minimal effort to complete some task by putting a burden of your work on the others.***